# How to make arguments to lattice functions be evaluated in data frame?

Tags: r, lattice, evaluation

When using lattice functions, like `xyplot()`, the variables in the `formula` and `group` arguments are evaluated inside the data frame `data`. So, for instance, the following works for colouring different groups with different colours:

```
df=data.frame(x=1:9, y=1:9,
              cluster=rep(c("first", "second", "third"), each=3),
              stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
xyplot(y~x, data=df, cex=3, groups=cluster)
```

[image]

But for other arguments, like `pch` or `labels`, it doesn’t work:

```
> xyplot(y~x, data=df, cex=3, pch=factor(cluster))
Error in factor(cluster) : object 'cluster' not found
```

I have to specify the data frame explicitly, like this:

```
xyplot(y~x, data=df, cex=3, pch=factor(df$cluster))
```

[image]

However, this is error-prone, as I have to remember to update the data frame used in two separate places. And it doesn’t seem to play nice with `groups`:

```
xyplot(y~x, data=df, cex=3, groups=cluster, pch=factor(df$cluster))
```

[image]

Here the `groups` colours are applied, but the `pch` shapes are not. And for the `labels` argument, it is the other way around:

[image]

```
xyplot(y~x, data=df, cex=3, groups=cluster, labels=df$cluster, panel=panel.text)
```

It also doesn’t play nice with conditioning panels:

```
xyplot(y~x | cluster, data=df, cex=3, labels=df$cluster, panel=panel.text)
```

[image]

So what is the recommended way to specify aesthetics, like point shape and label text, from the same data frame that is used for the formula and `groups` data?